# HBase data entry program not running properly

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2

Following is the code for data entry in HBase :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class SimpleDataEntry {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      // Instantiating Configuration class
      Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

      // Instantiating HTable class
      HTable hTable = new HTable(config, "emp");

      // Instantiating Put class
      // accepts a row name.
      Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1")); 

      // adding values using add() method
      // accepts column family name, qualifier/row name ,value
      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"),
      Bytes.toBytes("name"),Bytes.toBytes("raju"));

      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"),
      Bytes.toBytes("city"),Bytes.toBytes("hyderabad"));

      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("professional"),Bytes.toBytes("designation"),
      Bytes.toBytes("manager"));

      p.add(Bytes.toBytes("professional"),Bytes.toBytes("salary"),
      Bytes.toBytes("50000"));

      // Saving the put Instance to the HTable.
      hTable.put(p);
      System.out.println("data inserted");

      // closing HTable
      hTable.close();
   }
}
```

The error we are getting on running this code is :

```
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/home/hadoop1/hadoop1/lib/native
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hadoop1
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hadoop1
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hadoop1
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x5542c4ed0x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
16/04/24 14:07:58 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/04/24 14:07:58 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
16/04/24 14:07:58 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient ZooKeeper, quorum=localhost:2181, exception=org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
16/04/24 14:07:59 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
16/04/24 14:07:59 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

The hbase-site.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
   //Here you have to set the path where you want HBase to store its files.
   <property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/hbase</value>
   </property>

   //Here you have to set the path where you want HBase to store its built in zookeeper  files.
   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
      <value>/home/hadoop1/zookeeper</value>
   </property>

<property>
   <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>


<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2183</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>172.17.25.20</value>

</property>
</configuration>
```

What could be the possible problem and it's solution?

Answer (score 1):

Errors in log indicate that hbase-site.xml doesn't loaded correctly. Check your hbase-site.xml: It must be on your classpath, because `HbaseConfiguration.create()` load config from path which you set on classpath(and try to add it to the beginning of classpath to prevent loading of hbase-site.xml from other jar in which similar config file was embedded)
Also, it seems that you use hbase-site.xml from Hbase server: all config keys except hbase.zookeeper.quorum is redundant and useless in client.

Comment: What do u mean by "Check your hbase-site.xml: It must be on your classpath" ?

Comment: I mean that path to hbase-site.xml file must be added to Java classpath

Answer (score 1):

`Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();` Only creates an almost empty configuration file if java can not find hbase-site.xml.
To tell java where your conf file is, you can either put hbase-site.xml directly in your classpath, or you can call `conf.addResource(**hbase-site path**)`

**Edit**

As said in comment by Lagrang, try `conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","172.17.25.20:2183")`

Comment: Still getting the same error on adding 
`config.addResource("/home/hadoop1/hbase-1.1.4/conf/hbase-site.xml");`

Comment: Can you try `config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2183");`

Comment: @dorado, `config.addResource(String)` try to load configuration file it from Java classpath too. It wait classpath resource name, not path to file in random place.
`hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort` is the port at which the clients will connect at Zookeeper server side(not on client side). You have to set Zookeeper client port to which you want to connect in `hbase.zookeeper.quorum`(for instance, `172.17.25.20:2183`)

Comment: Little more about: `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort is the port at which the clients will connect at Zookeeper server side(not on client side).` This is server side property of Zookeeper when it run inside HBase server(e.g. not a standalone ZK server). In client app configuration it useless.